# How to convert [part1|part2] to just part1 in c#

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, text, uwp

Is there any way to convert a string that contains 
`Hello, [World|Universe]!`
 to a string that says
`Hello, World!`
in C#?
I have searched high and low through Google but couldn't find anything. Am I missing the keyword that this process is called?
The app will take a text file from online and parce it to take away certain parts, for example: "[He|Weston] ate an apple for breakfast." will be changed to: "He ate an apple for breakfast."

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part headed "Help others reproduce the problem". The question as written does not demonstrate any research effort.

Comment: There is no converter in C# that converts string words to other string words. You have to do this mauell

Comment: I mean if i have a string in a c# console app that contains [A|B] i want the program to change the given string to another string that contains just A.

Comment: I suspect `string.Split()` might be of value, but it is not clear why you would pick one part over the other

Comment: The app will take a text file from online and parce it to take away certain parts, example: "[He|Weston] ate an apple for breakfast." will be changed to: "He ate an apple for breakfast." That clear things up?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more context around the problem. What causes the code to choose `World` over `Universe`? What code have you tried? There are a number of questions on Stack Overflow about string manipulation in C#. Have you looked at those? Have any helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using string functions

```
public string ChageText(string text)
{ 
     //get the replace text
     var replace = text.Substring(text.IndexOf("["), text.IndexOf("]") - text.IndexOf("[") + 1);
     //split the replace text and append to original text
     return text.Replace(replace, replace.Split("|")[0].Replace("[", ""));
}
```

How to use

```
Console.WriteLine(ChangeText("Hello, [World|Universe]!"));
Console.WriteLine(ChangeText("[He|Weston] ate an apple for breakfast."));
```

OUTPUT

```
Hello, World!
He ate an apple for breakfast.
```

Comment: Thanks! that is exactly what I was trying to do!